# Microsoft Translator API v3, ASP.NET VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, microsoft-translator

I am trying to call on the MS Translator API through an ASP.NET function to translate various strings from a database.

All examples from MS are given in C# so I throw into a converter and go from there.
From my searching I'm pretty sure this is an async/await issue. I have also tried setting strString to different things at different times but it throws the same error as if I'm not awaiting properly.

From the aspx page I have this:

```
<%# functions.translate(Eval("Description").ToString) %>
```

`Description` is a field from a database and shows properly if not passed to the translate function. I have other functions that I call to do various things and work properly.

In my functions.vb I have:

```
Public Class TranslationResult
    Public Property Translations As Translation()
End Class

Public Class Translation
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Property [To] As String
End Class

Public Class functions

    Public Shared Async Function translate(strString As String) As Task(Of String)

        Dim host As String = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com"
        Dim route As String = "/translate?api-version=3.0&to=fr"
        Dim key As String = "0000000000000000000000000"
        Dim body As Object() = New Object() {New With {Key .Text = strString}}
        Dim requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body)

        Using client = New HttpClient()
            Using request = New HttpRequestMessage()
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Post
                request.RequestUri = New Uri(host & route)
                request.Content = New StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key)
                Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(False)
                Dim result As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                Dim deserializedOutput As TranslationResult() = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TranslationResult())(result)
                For Each o As TranslationResult In deserializedOutput
                    For Each t As Translation In o.Translations
                        strString = t.Text
                    Next
                Next
            End Using
        End Using

        Return strString

    End Function
```

The error I'm getting is on the web page showing `` System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String] `` when I'm expecting a translated string.

Comment: What is the c# version of the code you are trying to translate?

Comment: That method is declared `Async`, which means that if you return a `String` within it, it will return a `Task(Of String)`, which is why you see that full name of that type in your page.  To get the `String` result from the `Task`, you normally await the async method.  Not sure whether that's supported in ASPX or not but, if so, it would be `<%# Await functions.translate(Eval("Description").ToString) %>`.

Comment: The sample of code that was converted states "This sample requires C# 7.1 or later for async/await.  Adding await in front of functions.translate etc causes an error "'Await' can only be used when contained within a method or lambda expression marked with the 'Async' modifier."

Answer (score 0):

I used your code as base and got it working.  Just using a simple Webform.

[image]

Didn't change anything in the code, but I was prompted to add

```
Imports System.Net.Http
```

By Visual studio 2019

The final entire webform codebehind vb.aspx looks like this:

```
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class microsoftTranslator
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   dim translatedText =  functions.translate( "This is going to be one, two, three in french").Result

End Sub

Public Class TranslationResult
    Public Property Translations As Translation()
End Class

Public Class Translation
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Property [To] As String
End Class

Public Class functions

Public Shared Async Function translate(strString As String) As Task(Of String)

    Dim host As String = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com"
    Dim route As String = "/translate?api-version=3.0&to=fr"
    Dim key As String = "0000000000000000000000000"
    Dim body As Object() = New Object() {New With {Key .Text = strString}}
    Dim requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body)

    Using client = New HttpClient()
        Using request = New HttpRequestMessage()
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post
            request.RequestUri = New Uri(host & route)
            request.Content = New StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key)
            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(False)
            Dim result As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
            Dim deserializedOutput As TranslationResult() = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TranslationResult())(result)
            For Each o As TranslationResult In deserializedOutput
                For Each t As Translation In o.Translations
                    strString = t.Text
                Next
            Next
        End Using
    End Using

    Return strString

End Function
end class

End Class
```

To make it wait for the async result look at the `.result` property

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim APIUrlToSend As String = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=de"
        Dim MyMainRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create(APIUrlToSend), HttpWebRequest)
        MyMainRequest.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "YOUR API CODE")
        MyMainRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        MyMainRequest.Method = "POST"
        ' Send request
        Dim MyJavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim TextToTranslate As String = MyJavaScriptSerializer.Serialize("Text to translate")
        Dim MyMainRequestBody As String = "[{ Text: " & TextToTranslate & " }]"
        Dim MyMainRequestBytesData As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MyMainRequestBody)
        MyMainRequest.ContentLength = MyMainRequestBytesData.Length
        Using RequestWriteStream = MyMainRequest.GetRequestStream()
            RequestWriteStream.Write(MyMainRequestBytesData, 0, MyMainRequestBytesData.Length)
        End Using
        Dim MyFinalResponse As HttpWebResponse = MyMainRequest.GetResponse()
        Dim MyFinalResponseStream As Stream = MyFinalResponse.GetResponseStream
        Dim MyFinalResponseStreamReader As New StreamReader(MyFinalResponseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))
        Page.Response.Write(MyFinalResponseStreamReader.ReadToEnd())

    End Sub
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion